# Tailwindcss v3 not working with next.js v12

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

tailwindcss styles are not getting applied. What might be the issue? Tried multiple solutions in the `tailwind.config.js` file, but none of it worked.

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "twitter-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.31",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js :**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
}
```

Also, tried using the below code, but it too didn't work -

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js, ts, jsx, tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**postcss.config.js :**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

**globals.css :**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

[image: Folder structure for reference :]

Comment: Have you been though all the troubleshooting tips? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#troubleshooting

Comment: Try to restart the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be because of not importing the `globals.css` in `_app.tsx` file.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
```

I myself have removed the above line from my `_app.js` file multiple times (unknowingly) while removing the boilerplate code.